# How to programmatically click on elements in Electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, chromium, electron

I have an Electron application that relies on UI automation to play, pause, and skip from global-shortcut. On the website, I can use the jQuery `.click()` function and programmatically click on these elements. However, when the same site is embedded in Electron, the DOM changes - is there any way to click on specific elements from a webview in Electron?

Here's what Electron shows in source:

```
<body style="overflow:hidden;">
      <webview id="player" preload="./preload.js" src="https://play.google.com style="position:absolute;width:100%; height:100%" disablewebsecurity="" tabindex="-1"></webview> 
      <script>
      </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use jQuery. However, I urge you to move away from it and start realizing how powerful and similar vanilla JS, can be, making a stronger, lighter web app.

You can do this:

```
document.getElementById('player').click();
```

Keep in mind that anything you can do in a browser, you can also do in Electron!

Answer (score 2):

> On the website, I can use the jQuery .click() function

With electron you can also use jQuery exactly the same way.